# ee3 category group ordering

Tags: ee3, category-group

I have a category group in ee3 with 100+ categories that were imported. Is there a way I can get them to be sorted alpha without drag & drop manually in the control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this will be added to ee3 at some point, but you can work directly in the database to do this. *(Tested on mysql 5.6.34, ee 3.5.4, backup first!)*

```
-- set the user variable
SET @cat_order_val = 0;

-- reorder the cat_order column based on Category Url Title (alpha ascending)
UPDATE exp_categories 
    SET cat_order = (@cat_order_val := @cat_order_val + 1) 
    WHERE group_id = 1 
    ORDER BY cat_url_title ASC;
```

edit: added group_id condition, change to match your group id.

Comment: Thanks. That'll have to do for now. I just added the group_id and changed to sort by cat_name instead of url_title (not sure if the client changed any of those in the old site). Hopefully this gets into ee3 soon

Comment: Great.. Yes forgot group_id, so updated the example for future ref.